# Opportunity Name required on Create even for Before Save Record Triggered Flow

Tags: create-records, required-field, recordtriggeredflow, before-save-flow

I have a  Record Triggered Flow (Fast Update , before Save)
Flow is executed when an Opportunity is Created or Updated.

The flow auto populates the name of the Opportunity based on a standardized naming convention.

**My problem is this**

To be able to Save the new Opportunity, the Opportunity Name is Required. Which means the user has to type 'something'. Then, after clicking the Save button, that 'something'  will be replaced with the auto name from flow.

This may confuse the user initially. Unless we train them .

**Solutions I am thinking of -**

A Screen Flow with Create Record element. But I think that's too much.

The other option I am thinking is to train the users and also have a help text to remind users that whatever they type in the Opportunity Name field will get overwritten when the record is saved.

**I am interested in knowing what solutions have other's implemented ?**

Comment: I suspect they will self-learn quickly as whatever they type will be replaced by your Flow when the page refreshes and the new standardized name appears

Comment: _This may confuse the user initially. Unless we train them_ - sounds like you've answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

The "classic" way of doing this was to override the New button with a Visualforce page.  This page would exclude the Name field and allow the VF controller to default the name before the record is committed via the `Save` button.

The Visualforce page [could also invoke a flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_adding.htm) to do the work

**Option 2**

Override the New action with an Aura component

- [Example for New button](https://levelupsalesforce.com/how-to-override-standard-buttons-using-aura)
- [Documentation reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides_basics.htm)

**Option 3**

Let the users self-learn (training won't really be needed - the user will realize whatever they enter is standardized as soon as the page is refreshed after the `Save`).

---

*Note [this idea to override standard actions with LWC](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh53UAB/override-standard-button-using-lightning-web-component-lwc)*